# Can use sudo apt update

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, update-manager

```
himanshu_chhatwal@Himanshu:~$ sudo apt update 
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                         
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                 
Hit:3 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/blaze/rtbth-dkms/ubuntu jammy InRelease 
Hit:4 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/kiwixteam/release/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:5 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_19.x jammy InRelease                     
Hit:6 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                
Get:7 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease [17.1 kB]                 
Hit:8 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                
Hit:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Ign:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security InRelease
Err:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
Reading package lists... Done                                                  
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/dists/stable/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/focal-security.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/focal-security.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/focal-security.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/focal-security.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/focal-security.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/focal-security.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/focal-security.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/focal-security.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/focal-security.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/focal-security.list:1
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/focal-security.list:1
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/focal-security.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/focal-security.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/focal-security.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/focal-security.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/focal-security.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/focal-security.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/focal-security.list:1
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/focal-security.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/focal-security.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/focal-security.list:1
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/focal-security.list:1
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/focal-security.list:1
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/focal-security.list:1`
```

please help me out as i am stuck

Comment: Ubuntu 21.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/07/19/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-end-of-life-reached-on-july-14-2022/   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades   *You've not provided your OS/release details; but the impish error(s) are because it's EOL*

Comment: You've not provided your OS/release, but Ubuntu *impish* (21.10) is EOL thus errors on that archive are expected.  I also note other releases from *jammy* (22.04), *focal* (20.04) so what OS/release you're using is rather unclear..  As you trying to explore problems?

Answer (score 0):

I see sources from three different releases, including one that is past End of Life. And repeats of many sources. And no less than five PPAs and other Non-Ubuntu sources. It's a testament to the skill Debian and Ubuntu developers that this patchwork monster boots at all.

Advice: Back up your data and start over with a clean slate and a fresh install. You have learned a lot from this iteration, carry those lessons to the next:

- Never mix sources from different releases of Ubuntu.
- Avoid PPAs and non-Ubuntu sources unless you know how to maintain them. Keep in mind that you might need to remove them (and all their packages) if they cause version conflicts.
- If you want newer software on an older LTS release, look for Snaps instead of PPAs or non-Ubuntu deb sources.
- Take a few minutes and learn how to curate your sources. Look at the format, the purpose of each file, the purpose of each repository, how those sources drive `apt update`, and how you can use your output to solve a lot of problems.

Comment: Thanks, I was also thinking for the same